# TbButtonColumn $data error

Tags: php, yii

I'm trying to use `$data->id` on `TbButtonColumn` but I'm getting error `"Trying to get property of non-object"`.
The `TbGridView` is working properly!
What I'm doing wrong?

View.php:

```
<?php  $this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbGridView',array(
    'type'=>'striped bordered condensed',
    'id'=>'profiles-grid',
    'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
    'columns'=>array(
        'id',
        array(
            'class'=>'bootstrap.widgets.TbButtonColumn',
            'template'=>'{create}',
            'buttons'=>array
            (
                'create' => array(
                    'label'=>'Criar Evento',
                    'icon'=>'plus',
                    'url'=>'Yii::app()->controller->createUrl("events/create", array("id"=>$data->id))', // Problem here on $data->id
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
)); ?>
```

Comment: What kind of Data Provider is `$dataProvider`? If it doesn't contain models `$data->id` won't work.

Comment: @topher it have `id`column, and the `TbGridView` is working properly without `url`. It comes from `CSqlDataProvider`, I think heres the problem.

Comment: Found the problem. With `CSqlDataProvider` need to use `"id"=>$data["profile_id"]` instead `$data->id`. Thanks for everybody ;)

Comment: `CSqlDataProvider::getData()` method returns a list of arrays. So to access the `id` of an element try `$data['id']`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting the button's url like this worked for me:

```
'url'=>'$this->grid->controller->createUrl("update", array(
            "id"=>$data->primaryKey))',
```

Answer (score 1):

The error you're getting is caused by the fact that `$data` is not an object. You cannot use the property access operator `->` on any other variable type.

It is not clear from your question where `$data` is assigned a value, or what that value is supposed to be. You can ensure a variable contains an object using the `is_object` function:

```
if (!is_object($data))
  die('There seems to be a problem with the data');
```

This will tell you that `$data` isn't an object, thus preventing the error. BUT, I suspect the underlying problem is whatever mechanism you expect to populate the `$data` variable is failing, or not working in the way you expect.

You can use `var_dump` to debug variables and check their type in the process:

`var_dump($data);`

...this will give you a better idea of what `$data` actually is -- it isn't an object, that's for sure!

**Documentation**

- `is_object` - http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-object.php
- PHP article about variables - http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.php
- PHP article about objects - http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.object.php
- `var_dump` - http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php